# Как найти длину вектора в Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

В DataFrame каждая строка является вектором. Как вычислить длину каждого вектора?

Аналогичного поведения можно добиться следующим кодом:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
X = pd.DataFrame(...)
Zero = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(X.shape[0]), columns=X.columns)
L = cdist(X, Zero)
```

но думаю, что можно сделать проще. В примере генерируется нулевой DataFrame такой же формы, что и `X`, и вычисляется метрика Евклида между двумя DataFrame.

UPD. Пример исходного набора данных:

```
A       B       C
2       3       4 
2       1       2
5       4       2
```

Пример результата:

```
sqrt(2^2+3^2+4^2)
sqrt(2^2+1^2+2^2)
sqrt(5^2+4^2+2^2)
```

Comment: я себе эвклидову метрику немного по-другому представлял... Между чем и чем вы считаете расстояние (метрику)? Или вам надо посчитать расстояние между нулевым DF и указанным DF?

Comment: @MaxU, конечно же, корень забыл. Надо найти длину векторов, содержащихся в строках DataFrame. Эта операция эквивалентна нахождению расстояния между нулевым DF и моим DF. Возможно ли это сделать без создания дополнительных сущностей?

Comment: И ещё, я ошибся: cdist делает не то, что нужно: он считает метрику между каждой парой строк в двух наборах данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances) - в отличие от [scipy.spatial.distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) методов эта функция не будет делать лишних (в вашем случае) расчетов

Исходные DataFrame's:

```
In [81]: df
Out[81]:
   A  B  C
0  2  3  4
1  2  1  2
2  5  4  2

In [82]: Zero
Out[82]:
   A  B  C
0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0
```

Решение:

```
In [83]: from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import paired_distances

In [84]: paired_distances(df, Zero)
Out[84]: array([ 5.38516481,  3.        ,  6.70820393])
```

в качестве нового столбца

```
In [85]: df['dist'] = paired_distances(df, Zero)

In [86]: df
Out[86]:
   A  B  C      dist
0  2  3  4  5.385165
1  2  1  2  3.000000
2  5  4  2  6.708204
```